# mysql WHERE IN, but with multiple test values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked around on this site and on the net in general for this but haven't had any luck so far.

The question :

I have a table storing file information with a field that contains a comma-separated list of numeric values, identifying which groups can have access to each file.

Each user's active groups are stored in a session and therefore I need to compare the comma-separated list of numbers in the session with the comma-separated list stored in the table column.  If any of the groups in the session match any of the groups in the column, then the file is accessible.

For example :

Resource 1 has the rgroups field populated by "1,13,15" showing that those 3 groups can view the resource.

On the page that lists resources, I have the following query where $matches comes from a session of active groups :

```
SELECT * FROM resources WHERE rgroups IN ($matches)
```

Now this seems to work fine where 1 group is active — ie., WHERE 1 IN (1,13,15) — but what about when more than one group is active?

```
SELECT * FROM resources WHERE 1,14 IN (1,13,15)
```

Or do I need a different, more complex query?

Thanks!

Comment: use AND or OR for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on what Gordon Linoff said as well as something I saw elsewhere on the net.

The essence of the answer is  :

```
$matcharr = explode(",", $matches);

$mysqlwhere = "";
foreach($matcharr as $item){
$mysqlwhere .= "$item IN (rgroups) OR ";
}
$mysqlwhere = substr($mysqlwhere,0,-3);
$only4group = "AND (" . $mysqlwhere . ")";
```

I take the session of active groups in $matches and split it creating the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM resources WHERE rarea = 'shared' AND (1 IN (rgroups) OR 13 IN (rgroups) ) ORDER BY rarea, rname
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

An In clause is just a nested OR condition.
Where rgroups in ('1','13','15) is the same as saying Where (rgroups = '1' OR rgroups ='13' OR....)

just construct your SQL Statement in some sort of generic function and apply it against the DB.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You need a more complex query.  Also, I don't think your first version works.  The working version should use `like`:

```
where concat(',', $matches, ',') like concat('%,', rgroups, ',%')
```

You can extend the idea for multiple groups:

```
where concat(',', $matches, ',') like concat('%,', rgroup1, ',%') and
      concat(',', $matches, ',') like concat('%,', rgroup2, ',%') and
      concat(',', $matches, ',') like concat('%,', rgroup3, ',%')
```

Where `rgroup<n>` is an element of the groups.

If you know how many elements are in rgroups, you could do something like:

```
where find_in_set($matches, substring_index(rgroups, 1)) > 0 and
      find_in_set($matches, substring_index(rgroups, 2)) > 0 and
      find_in_set($matches, substring_index(rgroups, 3)) > 0
```

If you know a maximum value, you can try:

```
where (substring_index(rgroups, 1) = 0 or  find_in_set($matches, substring_index(rgroups, 1))) and
      (substring_index(rgroups, 2) = 0 or  find_in_set($matches, substring_index(rgroups, 2))) and
      (substring_index(rgroups, 3) = 0 or  find_in_set($matches, substring_index(rgroups, 3))) and
      . . .
```

Comment: My first version does actually work and I think even works when there are multiple values that are the same, ie. 1,3 in 1,3,5  but not when there are multiple non-matching values, ie. 1,6 in 1,3,5.  Thanks for your suggestion... I will try it out now.

Comment: But what I need to do is break up both values and check one array against the other... I'm just not sure how to do that in mysql

Comment: rgroup is a field, how could I split the field in mysql?

Comment: @Aethon . . . Are you generating the whole query as a string?  If so, then it might work.  Otherwise, you should use `like` or `find_in_set`.  I prefer the former just because it works across SQL dialects.

Comment: I am generating the whole thing as a string however, rgroups is being used as is -- but I don't know how many elements are in rgroups.  It could be one or many elements.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, Gordon, however, there is no maximum value of elements. :( I appreciate the time you're taking and I'll keep looking into solutions but if you have any other ideas, they are welcome as well :)

Comment: @Aethon . . . Store the lists in tables instead of strings.  Much more appropriate for a database anyway.

Comment: Hey Gordon, I'm not sure what you mean by storing the list in tables.  The list of groups for each user is held in a session and I need to compare those active groups to the list of groups in each resource.

Comment: Thanks for your help in pointing me in the right direction, Gordon :)